# Server-side SVG generator with NodeJS & Typescript

Tags: node.js, svg, d3.js

I am looking for a way to create SVGs via NodeJS & Typescript on the server. I tried using `D3.js` with `JSDOM` but I struggled with `ERR_REQUIRE_ESM` errors when importing `D3.js`. Does someone have another approach to solve this or maybe a snippet?

Comment: Are you using a temple engine in Node.js for HTML? Have you tried generating SVG with that?

Comment: you mean something lice `JSDOM`?

Comment: I was thinking of [handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars), [pug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug) etc., but jsdom could maybe also help you.

Answer (score 0):

Example in [pug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug) that generates a SVG element/document. The static array could be replaced by an object or array with data.

svgtemplate.pug:

```
svg(xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",viewBox="0 0 100 100")
  rect(width="100", height="100", fill="blue")
  each c in [{r:50,fill:"red"},{r:20,fill:"orange"}]
    circle(cx="50", cy="50", r=c.r, fill=c.fill)
```

JavaScript:

```
var pug = require('pug');

var svgdoc = pug.compileFileClient('/svgtemplate.pug', {title: "Test"});
```